# HTML File input returning wrong file size

Tags: html, file

i'm trying to upload photos and videos in `Html Page`

```
 <input type='file' /><br>
(The HTML page is used inside Resco CRM Mobile App)<br>
```

the problem is the File input returning Size 0 in case video
The Engine that the app is using is :
`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_2_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.4.6 (KHTML, Like Gecko) Mobile 14D27`

Comment: how is the File input returning Size 0? Show us your code

Comment: Are you using FileAPI for blob (resizing, etc)? mobile devices (android certainly can be pretty out of whack)

Comment: i'm not using any thing external only <input id="selectFiles" type="file" class="btn btn-primary btn-block pull-left" multiple>